# Android ebook reader

Tags: android, tablet, e-reader

I am looking for a new Android e-book reader. The primary requirements:

1. OS: Officially supports Android v6.
2. Weight: < 300gr, preferably < 250gr
3. Price: < $250
4. Dimensions: not large (roughly the size of the [Nexus 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_(2013)): 
   200mm × 114mm × 8.65mm)
5. Memory: > 16GB

Secondary requirements:

1. Pure or close-to-Pure Android (i.e., no bloatware)
2. Water-resistant
3. Comfortable to hold and read in one hand

Comment: Could it be a standard tablet?

Comment: @Benjamin, yes. I currently use a Nexus 7 but it is getting old and will not get Android updates anymore.

Comment: I think that it's important to point out that many (if not all) Android devices do not yet have Android 6.0.

Comment: Why do you want it to run Android? A kindle would be effective.

Comment: The ASUS Zenpad s 8 will be coming out soon. It has very low specs and is around your budget. Perhaps you should wait until September 25th for it's release.

Comment: @Firepower0701, I will use the device mainly for reading but not solely, I use other Android applications regularly and carrying around two 7" devices is not practical for me.

Comment: @michaelpri, by officially support I mean there is a official plan to have it run Android 6. E.g. Google has said it is not going to update Nexus 7.

Comment: Does “ebook reader” imply e-paper, or are you prepared to accept a backlit display?

Comment: @Gilles, doesn't imply e-paper.

Comment: @Kaveh If you take away the e-paper requirement and require the device to run Android it sounds to me like you are really asking for a tablet and not an e-book.

Comment: Posting this as a comment because I don't believe it fits the Android v6 requirement (yet) but Barnes&Noble Galaxy Tab Nook (http://nook.barnesandnoble.com/u/nook/379003208) is an option for an Android ereader.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet currently is probably to wait for the rumored upcoming Nexus 7 2016 revision, since you want a tablet that will stay updated and your current Nexus 7 (2013) did, in fact, get updated to Android 6 Marshmallow after all.

*Edit: As it turns out you already own the 2013 revision; the second segment has been left for posterity.*

Since you aren't requiring an e-paper display what you're effectively asking for is the 2013 revision of the Nexus 7.

1. The Nexus 7 (2013 model) supports Android 6 Marshmallow officially.
2. Both the Wifi and 3G models come in at 290g and 299g respectively.
3. It lists for well under $250 now, having launched at $229 for the 16GB model.
4. It's definitely the size of a Nexus 7.
5. The base model starts at 16GB and there is a 32GB model available.

Next requirements:

1. It runs stock android since it's a Nexus device.
2. This is the only requirement it doesn't make, and frankly, if you want real water resistance you're going to need a case, and that adds weight and size to any tablet. It can also add grippy texture or a strap which is something to keep in  mind.
3. This is a matter of opinion, but based on the size and rubberized type material of the back it sounds like many people can one hand it.

The only issue I see is that it's unclear whether the Nexus 7 (2013) will get an official OTA update for Android 7 Nougat, but there is some evidence that it might. You may also want to keep in mind that there are rumors of a new Nexus 7 releasing this year alongside the Nougat update and new Nexus phones. It might be a more compelling model and might also drop the prices of the older Nexus tablets like the 7's.

You're not going to get any closer to a stock experience than the Nexus line unless you're willing to dabble with ROMs.

Comment: I already have a Nexus 7 2013. At the time I asked the question Google did not include it in the list of devices that would be updated to Android 6, it was later added to the list. But more importantly Nexus 7 2013 is not sold officially anymore.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll get to editing this then, but that second fact is a benefit. They're pretty cheap now since they discontinued them for newer models. Still looking for a replacement?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for a replacement, one that will keep being updated. There are rumors that Google might release a new version this year according to some news sites but so far Google hasn't given any sign that is going to happen, there was no mention of it at I/O 2016.